How to create Radial Basis Function Network for Regression problem in python using Tensorflow (keras)
I am working on a non-linear regression problem using a dataset with over 100 sensor data columns and a single output column containing real numbers ranging from 0 to 10,000. I have implemented a Multilayer Perceptron (MLP) network but it is not training well. I am considering more complex non-linear regression networks, and Radial Basis Function (RBF) networks have come up as a potential solution.
Here is the current implementation of my MLP network:
def create_dense_model(input_shape, num_outputs, LR, dropout_rate=0.3):
    he_avg_init = initializers.VarianceScaling(scale=2., mode='fan_avg', distribution='uniform')
    inputs = Input(shape=input_shape)

    x = Dense(units=50, kernel_initializer=he_avg_init)(inputs)
    x = PReLU()(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)

    x = Dense(units=40, kernel_initializer=he_avg_init)(x)
    x = PReLU()(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)

    
    x = Dense(units=15, kernel_initializer=he_avg_init)(x)
    x = PReLU()(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)

    x = Dense(units=15, kernel_initializer=he_avg_init)(x)
    x = PReLU()(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)

    
    outputs = Dense(units=num_outputs, activation="relu")(x) 
    model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
    model.compile(loss=MeanSquaredError(),
                  metrics=["mean_squared_error"],
                  optimizer=RMSprop(learning_rate=LR))

    return model

I need help converting the MLP network to a RBF network.

More layers would help the net capture more complex relationships. Other models might also be useful here, like random forest regressors and gradient boosting methods - they work especially well with tabular data. If some sample data is available I might be able to try a few models.
